# .NET Remoting Client's Problem when running on the machine with Multi NICs

Tags: .net, remoting, nic

I built a .NET Remoting Client which works quite fine on the machine of single NIC, and lots of testing messages received via remoting event.

But when additional NIC was added, the Client seemed to be able to connect the remoting Server, but the testing messages cannot arrive anymore.

From debugging, the server end did trigger the event but the client didn't get that. Checking from google and find that a similar problem report:
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10061570/reply.aspx

I just wonder if any solutions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just so you know - .NET Remoting has been deprecated in favor of WCF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was some problem for me also.

The nature of this problem is how client registers the event handlers on the server. When adding an event handler the client is sending the IP address of the "binded" address. This is static non public field in the TcpChannel class (thank you reflector). You need to explicitly bind the client to the ip address that the server will be able to reach. The config file for the client should be something like this.

```
<channel ref="tcp" port="0" bindTo="your.ip.address.here" >
```

Comment: Or string machineName = System.Environment.MachineName;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(machineName))
                {
                    channelSettings.Add("machineName", machineName);
                }

Answer (score 1):

I am having problem making my .Net Remoting c# client-server program to work
and to connect to each other when there's router in between the client and
the server.

set on the client side

useIpAddress= false

example:

```
  <system.runtime.remoting>
    <application name="Client">
      <channels>
        <channel ref="tcp" port="0" useIpAddress="false">
          <clientProviders>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.channels.tcp.tcpchannel(v=vs.71).aspx